# Shapefiles for OECD United States Regions?

Tags: geospatial, oecd

I'm looking for Shape files that match up with the OECD TL3 US regions. I've tried contacting the OECD but they have not replied.

so, i followed the links in the OECD document (below) where they are meant to explain reference shape files. However, they reported that they used the 'Census Bureau, 2015 Cartographic Boundary Shapefiles - Counties'. This is not right

It seems that the admin names used by the OECD are from different sources - i've combined all of the shape files from the cencus Bureau site (e.g. County District, Division, Statistical Area etc) and quered these against the OECD region names, but i only get 100 matches out of a possible 170 oecd region names.

Can anyone help?

http://www.oecd.org/cfe/regional-policy/territorial-grids-2017.pdf

Comment: those look like cbsa, https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/cbf/cbf_msa.html

Comment: thanks, yes i tried those they only partially match, god knows what the oecd used

Comment: what doesn't match?

Comment: Thanks albert, i get 75 matches out of a possible 182  with the cbsa files (all years) and 22/23 (all years) with the cba files.

Comment: anyway you can share that? hard to help without knowing what you mean.